# What the means by the term ''ASP.NET Core is no longer based on System.Web.dll""?

Tags: asp.net-core

I read an [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) about `Asp.net Core`, it said that

> ASP.NET Core is no longer based on System.Web.dll

and in addition it said:

> It is based on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages. This allows you to optimize your app to include just the NuGet packages you need.

I googled about it, but i didn't find a good explanation, any one can clarify this for me?

Comment: It means that ASP.NET Core does no longer depend on the functionality that is provided in `System.Web.dll` .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your answering, do u have a good article or link about it for more explanation?

Comment: @pejman original [link from your question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) is good enough :) What exactly you want to know?

Comment: @Dmitry in this article just said that asp.net core has these option, for example it doesnt depend on `dll`, but it doesn't said its good or not and why! i want more explanation, some option are not clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core removed dependency on `System.Web` namespace/assemblies, because it was very old (it has it's roots in old ASP, long before ASP.NET Webforms came to the light) and very tightly coupled to IIS. Continue to support `System.Web` would mean, ASP.NET Core applications wouldn't be able to be ported well on Linux or Mac.

So removing this dependency allows ASP.NET Core to run on it's own and webserver independent, which makes it easier to port and host under linux or mac.

It's good, because this allows it to be hosted anywhere. But it also means, all libraries and extensions (which depend on `System.Web.*`) for the old ASP.NET WebForms/MVC webstacks are incompatible with ASP.NET Core and need a major redesign to remove these dependencies.

In the long run all major libraries for the ASP.NET legacy frameworks will be ported or coded from scratch at some point, since ASP.NET Core is the future.

So switching to ASP.NET Core for production applications may be a bit early, if they have many of that old dependencies which aren't available yet for ASP.NET Core.